# Sending the PUT request with Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded and sending image file not working

Tags: spring-mvc

When I send PUT request with **content-type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded** and wrong content like image; the request is not getting handled by server properly and it sends back following exception without any processing by server:

> ERROR;Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception;
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URLDecoder: Illegal hex characters in escape (%) pattern - For input string: "h�"
>       at java.net.URLDecoder.decode(URLDecoder.java:194)
>       at org.springframework.http.converter.FormHttpMessageConverter.read(FormHttpMessageConverter.java:241)
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:100)
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81)
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
>       at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:474)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349)
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:783)
>       at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
>       at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:798)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1434)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Is their any way in Spring through which we can handle the scenario ?

Comment: Paste your html code and controller code too.

Answer (score 0):

Files need to be multipart/form-data content-type

You basically have three choices:

1. Base64 encode the file, at the expense of increasing the data size by around 33%.
2. Send the file first in a multipart/form-data POST, and return an ID to the client. The client then sends the metadata with the ID, and the server re-associates the file and the metadata.
3. Send the metadata first, and return an ID to the client. The client then sends the file with the ID, and the server re-associates the file and the metadata.